# How to make TextView in Android wrap and adjust text beautifully?

Tags: android, textview

When text is small then I get this:

[image]

But when text is big I get this:

[image]

Is it possible that text adjust itself by maybe better using spaces or decreasing little size automatically?

This is my TextView xml:

```
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/seaGreen"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="35sp" />
```

Comment: nope for that you need to use external library for that, else you can set gravity as center

Comment: @Madhur Which library? Any idea

Comment: Have you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/5535672/1549865

Answer (score 1):

For that you need to use external library for that, else you can set gravity as center

**Library :**

https://github.com/grantland/android-autofittextview

For Text Justify

https://github.com/bluejamesbond/TextJustify-Android

https://github.com/programingjd/justified

OR

you can check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5535672/1549865)

Answer (score 1):

```
this work for me:    
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/your_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text=""
        android:textSize="14sp"/>
```